# Check if session is expired, then redirect (Joomla)

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

what I am trying to do is so simple but I can't find a clue on how to make it happen.

I have a huge form that is made of several php files and these files being called using AJAX that user has to fill, what exactly I want to achieve is:

1) test if session has expired on every page of this form.

2) if session is expired, I want to redirect him to a specific URL, let's say http://www.example.com

Thanks in advance for your help.
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that comes to my mind is to check if session cookie exists.
If session is active then by default PHP session mechanism uses cookie with default name 'PHPSESSID'. So if cookie PHPSESSID exists, your session is active.

You can check if session cookie exists like this:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])) {
    echo 'Session is active!';
} else {
    echo 'Session is not active!';
}
```

To redirect you can use this:

```
header('Location: http://example.com');
```

And to check for session cookie name use this:

```
session_start();
echo 'Session cookie name is: ' . session_name();
```

By default its 'PHPSESSID', but you or server admin could change that so check it out!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the session is active by using

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();

if ($session->isActive()) {
}
```